# Visiting Warsaw Rising Museum with luggage

Tags: luggage-storage, museums, warsaw

I was planning to visit the [Warsaw Uprising Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_Uprising_Museum) and might still be with all or some of my luggage when I get there. What are the access restrictions with luggage into the museum and are there any (lockers or guarded) luggage storage facilities available?

Specifically:

- can I visit the museum with a (medium/large 55l) backpack?
- alternatively can I store said backpack
- in case I tug along my suitcase, is there a place where I can store it?

Comment: In most countries main railway stations are better places to store luggage than museums, so do check out that option first.

Comment: You might be able to get more information by contacting the museum, http://www.1944.pl/en

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I did pay a visit to the museum and while I did not carry along any (heavy) luggage I can answer all of the questions:

> - can I visit the museum with a (medium/large 55l) backpack?

I saw two guys with medium sized backpacks (ca. 30l) being asked by the guards to store them. My slightly smaller shoulder pack (ca. 20l) was fine however.
The museum has plenty of stairs and uneven terrain so if you can spare your belongings for an hour or two, I would recommend you to do so.

> - alternatively can I store said backpack

Yes, there are luggage lockers in the museum square, right on your left when you enter. They look like this

[image]

and seemed spacious enough to hold even a large backpackers pack much larger than my 55l one. The locker is also very deep and can easily fit a couple of smaller backpacks. Keep a 5 zloty coin as a deposit handy.

> - in case I tug along my suitcase, is there a place where I can store it?

Yes, there is a manned cloakroom right after the ticket check and entrance on your left, first room of the building and you can't miss it. By chance another visitor had a massive suitcase with her and it was stored there for her. I don't know if they charge a fee for this or ask a tip but I would be surprised if so or if it were not moderate.

[image]

### Other things to take note:

Be aware the museum only opened from 10am in July and August 2016 (instead of 8am) which I somehow failed to notice on their website.

Comment: @pnuts a) I spent one hour in the museum but that was because I had not planned with the later opening, otherwise I could have spent two hours  easily (or three with a stop to their cafe). b) see my edit and while I was fine with my little bag, anything larger would have been uncomfortable, especially in a longer visit I would not have wanted a rucksack on my shoulders. Also if you plan to visit, give a good look to the floor plan across the cloakroom before entering, it will save you from some of the confusion I experienced.

Comment: According to google I did enter at a less busy time and still it felt full especially in the beginning. Ping me on chat or elsewhere if you do happen to go @pnuts.